# How to write a list of dicts to a csv and create a pandas dataframe from the CSV buffer in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to create a csv object from a list of dicts and then create a pandas dataframe by reading that csv object as a string buffer. But the resultant pandas dataframe doesn't look right to me. I am not sure how to format it correctly. I was wondering if anyone could suggest me right approach. Here is the code which I am using:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import csv
data = [{"x":123,"y":146},{"x":146,"y":None},
           {"x":187,"y":123},{"x":114,"y":184},{"x":1328,"y":977}]
output = io.StringIO()
writer = csv.writer(output, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
writer.writerow(data)
output.getvalue()
pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(output.getvalue()))
```

The last line generates the following in one single line:

```
{'x': 123, 'y': 146}    {'x': 146, 'y': None}   {'x': 187, 'y': 123}    {'x': 114, 'y': 184}    {'x': 1328, 'y': 977}
```

I would like to format this as `x` and `y` as column names and the respective values as the rows.

Thanks

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it. I am currently building that list of dicts on the fly and then pass the entire list of lets say more than 600,000 records to the dataframe to create one. It is pretty slow because of this process. So, I was wondering if I could use a buffer IO stream instead of the list of dicts and pass that straight to create a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code -

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{"x":123,"y":146},
        {"x":146,"y":None},
        {"x":187,"y":123}, 
        {"x":114,"y":184},
        {"x":1328,"y":977}]

data = pd.DataFrame(data)
data.to_csv("/tmp/test.csv", index=None)
pd.read_csv('/tmp/test.csv', index_col=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much easier way to do it

```
import json
import pandas as pd

data = [{"x":123,"y":146},{"x":146,"y":None},
       {"x":187,"y":123},{"x":114,"y":184},{"x":1328,"y":977}]

data = json.dumps(data)
df = pd.read_json(data)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
      x      y
0   123  146.0
1   146    NaN
2   187  123.0
3   114  184.0
4  1328  977.0
```

Note that column "y" is coerced to float because NaN is a float.